# Error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" en datatables.net cuando se ajusta a una pantalla chica (responsive)

Tags: jquery, datatables

Tengo mi datatables funcional cuando esta en una resolución alta, pero cuando esta en una pantalla chica no captura los datos del servidor.

Pantalla grande:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pantalla chica:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como sino reconociera cada fila correctamente.

Acá la forma en la que creo la tabla con datatables:

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    filter: false,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    autoWidth: true,
    ajax: {
        url: 'tabla/usuarios',
        global: false,
        method: 'POST',
        data: function (d) {
            d.campo = $('input[name=filter_campo]').val();
            d.perfil = $('select[name=filter_perfil]').val();
            d.estados = $('select[name=filter_estados]').val();
        }
    },
    columns: [
            {data: 0, searchable: false, orderable: false, render: function( data, type, full, meta ){
                return meta.row+1;
            }
        },
        {data: 1},
        {data: 2},
        {data: 10},
        {data: 11},
        {data: 5, 
            render: function( data, type, full, meta ){
                if (data) {
                    return '';
                }else {
                    return '';
                }
            }
        },
        {data: 9, searchable: false, orderable: false},
    ],
    search: {
        "regex": true
    },
    order: [[1, 'asc']],
    fnDrawCallback: function() {
        $("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapToggle();
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
            placement : 'top',
            html : true
        }); 
    }
});

editar("#table tbody",table);
```

Como obtengo los datos de la tabla al hacer clic en uno de los botones, ej "Editar":

```
var editar = function(tbody, table){
        $(tbody).on("click","button.editar", function(){
            var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
            $('#editar_id').val(data[0]);
            $('#editar_alias').val(data[1]);
            $('#editar_correo').val(data[2]);
            $('#editar_perfil').val(data[8]);
            $('#ModalEditar').modal('show');
            $("#editar-alias").first().focus();
        })
    }
```

[La demostración de la web del plugin](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/initialisation/ajax.html)

**Nota:** en el `responsive` pierde la propiedad el [botón tipo switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/)

**Actualización 1:**
Acá el error que arroja la consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la captura de pantalla dice que el error cae en la línea `usuarios:1228`, ¿puedes por favor actualizar tu pregunta resaltando la línea de código del error?

Comment: @Mauricio listo, actualizado :D

Comment: @Mauricio imprimo valor con "console.debug(data)" y me dice "undefined"

Comment: Pablo, el error se debe a que `data` no tiene datos y antes de esta línea: `$('#editar_id').val(data[0]);` debes validar que `data` sea diferente de `undefined`. Revisa bien qué valores llegan aquí: `var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();`

Comment: Explico. Datatables en cada fila tiene su data, pero cuando se vuelve responsive crea otra fila, y en esa file no está almacenada la data.

Comment: Lo que yo entiendo como funciona el plugin: cuando la tabla esta completa (no responsive) la data esta guardado en cada fila y se captura con "var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();" obteniendo el valor de la fila en la cual se encuentra el botón al cual le dio clic. ¿Que sucede cuando esta en una pantalla pequeña (responsive)? Crea otra fila la cual no es la que tiene la data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con el plugin datatables cuando se vuelve responsive se crea otra fila, como podemos verlo acá:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para capturar la data tenemos que diferenciar si el boton esta en una columna hijo, de la siguiente manera:

```
var editar = function(tbody, table){
    $(tbody).on("click","button.editar", function(){
        if(table.row(this).child.isShown()){
            var data = table.row(this).data();
        }else{
            var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
        }
        $('#editar_id').val(data[0]);
        $('#editar_alias').val(data[1]);
        $('#editar_correo').val(data[2]);
        $('#editar_perfil').val(data[8]);
        $('#editar_ver_perfil').val(data[4]);
        $('#ModalEditar').modal('show');
        $("#editar-nombres").first().focus();
    })
}
```